# escapeUrl is deprecated?

Tags: magento2.4, deprecated

Can someone help & explain to me what does escapeUrl is deprecated mean? What I need to do for the changes?

thanks

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getQtyOrdered() ?> x <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($productUrl) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductName($item->getProductId()) ?></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Magento version 2.4.* **$block->escapeUrl** is deprecated in templates and in blocks.

> Now you can use $escaper directly in templates and in blocks.

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getQtyOrdered() ?> x <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($productUrl) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductName($item->getProductId()) ?></a>
```